# Java List<?> Set Method

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am trying to change the value of a certain value in a List, but I am having trouble finding a way to do it, with the set method.

```
List<?> row = rse.next();
index = row.indexOf("nyc");
row.set(index, "New York");
```

So I grab a row of results from a resultset into an ArrayList, I am forced to do this so I use an ArrayList, or an array.  I have to use List.

I know the values are all String, is there a way to find "nyc" in the list, and replace it with "New York".  Currently the code above gives this error:

```
The method set(int, capture#4-of ?) in the type List<capture#4-of ?> is not
applicable for the arguments (int, String)
```

Comment: If you know that the values in the list are all of type String, why don't you just cast the list to the right type? Like this: `List<String> row = (List<String>) rse.next();`

Answer (score 7):

Your reference 
`List<?>`
 is a wildcard type, change it to 
`List<String>`
 if you know the list is of String's and it should work.

Comment: No problem! That is one of my least favorite error messages in Java, but once you know what it means it's an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

Accoding to `Java` documentation collections typed with wildcard can be modified, because you can know what is the real type the collection could support.

You can use `super` keyword to retrieve bounds in collection.

```
List<? super String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add( new String( "one" ) );
list.set( 0,"two"  );
```

Visit: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/